# EF queries receive generics, dynamically creates instances based on table names and is used for generic parameters of EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public static void CreateInstance()
{
    using (var ru = new RepositoryUse())
    {
        //封的查询
        var list1 = ru.SysUserRepository.IQueryable().ToList();
        //自定义SQL语句
        var list2 = ru.Context.Set<SysUser>().FromSql("select * from sysuser").ToList();

        //以上是常规的查询

        //问题，SysUser 实体未知

        //页面传一个变量 
        string tableName = "SysUser";

        //这里通过tableName的参数动态创建一个SysUser的实体，且可以传到Set<TEntity>
        //stringToTEntity(tableName)

        //这个是C#动态创建实例，但是这里的dm是object 需要 as SysUser才能用
        var dm = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Domain.SysUser"));
        var domain = dm as SysUser;

        //那么，说了这么多，有没有其它的方法来解决这个问题，或者说，改写Set方法
    }
}
```

EF queries receive generics, dynamically creates instances based on table names and is used for generic parameters of EF

---

Translated by Google Translate:

```
Public static void CreateInstance()
{
     Using (var ru = new RepositoryUse())
     {
         //closed query
         Var list1 = ru.SysUserRepository.IQueryable().ToList();
         // Custom SQL statement
         Var list2 = ru.Context.Set<SysUser>().FromSql("select * from sysuser").ToList();

         //The above is a regular query

         //Question, unknown SysUser entity

         //The page passes a variable
         String tableName = "SysUser";

         // Create a SysUser entity dynamically through the tableName parameter, and can be passed to Set <TEntity>
         //stringToTEntity(tableName)

         // This is a C # dynamically create an instance, but here dm is object need as SysUser can use
         Var dm = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Domain.SysUser"));
         Var domain = dm as SysUser;

         //Say, there are so many, there is no other way to solve this problem, or rewrite the Set method
     }
}
```

Comment: Please translate your comments to english | 请将您的意见翻译成英文